# Is it possible to execute a command as a super user while using cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a project that uses the [proxygen](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1503205539947302/introducing-proxygen-facebook-s-c-http-framework/) library by facebook.
The latter builds itself by means of a script called `deps.sh` which uses to invoke `apt-get` as a super user.
I've successfully created a custom target with `cmake` using the `add_custom_target` directive, but it fails because of the above call with the error `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` and it makes sense, of course.

Anyway I've not been able to find a way of executing that script, thus invoking a command as a super user, using the `add_custom_target`.
I can safely install the library and write a `FindProxygen` module for my colleagues, so that the build process remains coherent, but I'd like to know if there is a clean solution to the problem of launching a command as root from `cmake` and thus put the library as a submodule of the project.

Comment: `Find<project-name>` module is usually expects project being already installed at the moment `find_package()` call, that is **configuration** stage. So, installing `proxygen` in `add_custom_target` is not suitable for you: it executes commands at **build** stage. Anyway, execution of some command under super user is not a cmake-specific problem: it is up to you, how administator permissions will be requested during project's installing (or another stage).

Comment: Tsyvarev is correct, you need to install `proxygen` at or before configuration time. Instead of adding a custom target, install `proxygen` manually or from some `install-deps.sh` script or call `execute_process` in configuration time (call it conditionally so don't install if it's already installed). I guess you can set up askpass in `execute_process` the same way as normally.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'd like to add proxygen as a submodule (we're using git) to freeze its hash, but doing that means also compile it once downloaded and that means execute a custom command that requires root privileges. I understand that it's tricky and using find* is a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is pretty simple: no.

As remarked in the comments, *cmake* expects to find all the required libraries already installed in the system (or at least, within the search paths) and any other solution would stop the execution and wait for user inputs.

As far as I've seen around, the usual approach, the one I've used too in the above mentioned project and in another one started immediately after, is to create a script that is in charge to download, compile and prepare the project environment, the same way *proxygen* itself does.

The final user will be asked to firstly executes that script, thus he will be able to proceed using *cmake*.

That's all, thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can run installation script in new terminal, so `sudo`, executed by this script, will work as usual.

```
COMMAND x-terminal-emulator -e "<...>/deps.sh"
```

(This may be written as part of `add_custom_target`, `add_custom_command`, `execute_process`, etc.)

Comment: That worked nicely for me, but a limitation is that cmake goes forward, without waiting for the job running in the new terminal to be finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
    add_custom_target(
            apt-downloads ALL
            COMMAND sudo apt install -y ${DEPENDENCY_LIBRARIES}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
            COMMENT "download required dependencies straight from apt on ubuntu"
    )
```

Worked for me